# Flip animation is broken when having inside element with position property

Tags: css, animation, position, transform, flip

Flip animation is not working correctly if it has some element inside with `position` property. **This can be only reproduced on the first hover attempt after the page load**.

Does anyone know why it has such behavior?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__logo">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="card__burger">
      <div class="relative">Menu</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.card {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  &__logo,
  &__burger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__burger {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.parent:hover {
  .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}


.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Codeopen example](https://codepen.io/bogdan-liba/pen/xvdJGx)

**Update**: I can reproduce this only in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have different code but this will help you.

```
<style>

.flip-card {
        background-color: transparent; width: 100px;
        height: 100px; perspective: 1000px; margin-left:16%;
    }

    .flip-card-inner {
        position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;
        text-align: center; transition: transform 0.6s; transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    }

    .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner { transform: rotateY(180deg); }

    .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back { 
        position: absolute; width: 100%;
        height: 100%; backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .flip-card-front {
      background-color: #ffffff; color: black; z-index: 2;
    }

    .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #ffffff; color: white;
      transform: rotateY(180deg); z-index: 1;
    }
    .coninstallbtn { margin-top: 31%; margin-left: 20%; }

</style>

<body>

 <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
         <div class="flip-card-front">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-success coninstallbtn"> Front View </a>
         </div>
         <div class="flip-card-back">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-success coninstallbtn"> Back View </a>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div> 

</body>
```